I'm getting an incredible error in the for loop in c language. For loop works in 1,2 and 3 but stops suddenly
I know it's a cliché title but it really is.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int chances = 5;         //You can change your chances in there
char sentence[20];      //You can change your sentence's lenght. BUT İF U CHANGE THAT u have change indicator'S lenght
char indicator[20];     //İndicator
char character;         //Variable for your guess 

int woncheck = 0;

void status();          //function
void check();           //function

void main() {

    printf("Wellcome to my hangman game");
    printf("Player 1 please enter your sentence [Max 20 character] ==> ");  
    gets(sentence);         //Get sentence
    
    while (strlen(sentence)>=20)    //Checking for less than 20 char
    {
        printf("Please enter max 20 character ==> ");
        gets(sentence);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {  // The indicator takes _ as long as the sentence
        if (sentence[i] != ' ') {
            indicator[i] = '_';
        } else {
            indicator[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");   //Screen was skipped 

    status(); //Shows sentence's lenght before all of all

    for (int j = 0; j < chances ; j++) //We gave [changes] rights, so we create loops for a [changes] times
    {
        woncheck = 1;   //We need to check the game

        for (int k = 0; k < strlen(sentence); k++) {
            if (indicator[k] == '_') { // if any indicator letter's is not equal to '_' , it is mean, we not won the game yet
                woncheck = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (woncheck == 1) {
            printf("Player 1 won the game\n");
            break;
        }
    
        printf("Player 2 please enter 1 character ==> ");   //Let's gets letter
        scanf(" %c",&character);
        printf("\n");
        chances--;      // -1 Chance
        check();    //Checking
        status();   //Now where we are in status
        
        if (chances == 0) {
            printf("Player 1 lost the game\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void status() {
    for (int  i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++)     //As long as the sentence...
    {
/*         if (sentence[i]==' ')       //İf yours sentences have space, we give space
           {
           printf(" ");
           }
*/        printf("%c ",indicator[i]);     //We print the indicator equal to the length of the sentence
    }

    printf("You have %d chances left. \n \n",chances);
}

void check() {
    for (int  i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++)
    {
        if (toupper(sentence[i]) == toupper(character))     //if any sentece's letter equal to yours letter indicator gets your letter 
        {
            indicator[i] = character;
        }
        
    }
}


It's basic hangman game.
But if i try enter 3. letter, program is closing
I tryed these code in 2 ide + online compiler but all the time i guess i got logic error.
I request you to try it on your own computer and see if it works.
If it is not working or you found an error, I would appreciate it if you could add it to the comment.
Thanks in advance...

Stop using gets() immediately. It's a dangerous function and has been removed from the language.

strlen(sentence)>=20 can never be true. sentence is char[20], so the length can be at most 19.

Don't use global variables. If another function needs that variable, then pass it as an argument.

Also please try to use consistent indentation and formatting in general. That will make the code much easier to read and follow.

Given char sentence[20], if while (strlen(sentence)>=20) is ever true your code is already horribly broken.

but if ı use scanf() i can't use space or 2 sentences

Use fgets() instead of gets().

And you have five for loops. Which is the one giving you problems? Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also please try to use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

My problem is that when I try to guess the letter for the third time, the program closes.

u can try this code in online compiler

Among other cautions on style: void main() { ... } is wrong. Between that, gets and all of the global variables, it might be a good to check out a good modern book.

 for (int j = 0; j < chances ; j++) in there, if i change chances part loops worked good.

@Chris am I always need to use int main ?.

Avoid using magic numbers like 20, which you have to repeat all through your code. This is opening you up to errors, especially if you decide to change the string length limit. Use a named constant instead. Note that the character limit is not 20, but 19, because you need one byte of storage for the string's null terminator.

@BeratZengin int main() { ... } or int main(void) { ... } if you don't want access to command line arguments. The latter of those two if you want to be able to compile with -Wpedantic or the equivalent without issue.

Apart from the issues pointed out by others, your guessing loop for (int j = 0; j < chances ; j++) kicks out early because you're decrementing chances AND incrementing j.

@Chris i don't wait return in main so i didn't want use ´´´ int main ´´´ also thanks mr chris.

@PaulLynch LOL  u are right mr paul. How did I not see this?

@Berat Try while (chances) instead of the for (int j = 0; j < chances ; j++) loop.

I found that the problem was between ´´´ 5 and chances ´´´ , but I didn't fully understand it. i appreciative for your answer

Ignoring the other problems with your code, and addressing only the claimed issue of the game loop ending prematurely, I can see you are counting the "chances" in two conflicting ways.
for (int j = 0; j < chances ; j++)
{
    // (omitted)

    chances--;      // -1 Chance
    check();    //Checking
    status();   //Now where we are in status
    
    if (chances == 0) {
        printf("Player 1 lost the game\n");
        break;
    }
}

You start with a variable chances that is initialized to the value 5, and you construct a for loop using j to loop chances times.
However, in that loop you are also reducing chances by 1 every time before continuing the loop. That means your variable states when testing

after the first iteration, chances is 4
after the second iteration, chances is 3
after the third iteration, chances is 2 and this now fails the continuation condition.

You should choose only one approach. Either track the game progress with j only and do not modify chances, or only use chances as follows:
while (chances > 0)
{
    // (omitted)

    chances--;      // -1 Chance
    check();    //Checking
    status();   //Now where we are in status
}

if (woncheck) {
    printf("Player 1 won the game\n");
} else {
    printf("Player 1 lost the game\n");
}


u are right mr @paddy ı saw that 2 min ago and thanks for your answer appreciate it

Despite you have been answered, and the answer selected.  I cannot resist to answer to a comment you put in your code:
int chances = 5;         //You can change your chances in there
char sentence[20];      //You can change your sentence's lenght. BUT İF U CHANGE THAT u have change indicator'S lenght
char indicator[20];     //İndicator
char character;         //Variable for your guess 

you say

BUT IF U CHANGE THAT u have to change indicator's length too. (sorry about the different spelling)

For that you don't need to add a comment as such.... just
#define MAX_INDICATOR_LENGTH    20  /* you can change it as you wish, no compromises */

int chances = 5;         //You can change your chances in there
char sentence[MAX_INDICATOR_LENGTH];
char indicator[MAX_INDICATOR_LENGTH];     //İndicator
char character;         //Variable for your guess 

:)
